# Determine the DC of a magical item

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am a CL7 Wizard and want to create a Wand of Silence and just do not know how to determine the DC of the silence spell.

I create the wand together with a CL4 Cleric since the spell is not on my list.

Is the 
DC 10 + 2 (Second Level Spell) + 6 (Int value of the wizard) **or** 3 (Wis value of the cleric).

During the creation a second question occured. Can I heighten the DC by casting Fox Cunning on me before I do the spellcast check for creating the item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Magic Items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items) on [Saving Throws Against Magic Item Powers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Saving-Throws-Against-Magic-Item-Po) says

> Magic items produce spells or spell-like effects. For a saving throw against a spell or spell-like effect from a magic item, the DC is 10 + the level of the spell or effect + the ability modifier of the minimum ability score needed to cast that level of spell.

Thus the effect created by the typical *[wand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Wands) of [silence](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/silence)* has a save DC of 13 (base 10 + 2 for a 2nd-level spell +1 for a minimum casting ability score of 12 that's needed to cast the spell).

Increasing the ability scores of the folks making magic items doesn't typically improve the saving throw DCs of the magic items they create. Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11028/8610).

Comment: So in short, 10 + (1.5 x spell lv), rounded down. Easier to remember :)

Comment: Interesting link. First thought was metamagic to get the DC up since otherwise a DC13 is useless since we play mythic level 7 atm. But the rise in costs is imense. Anyway. Thanks for the answer! Oh, "Staves are an exception to the rule. Treat the saving throw as if the wielder cast the spell, including caster level and all modifiers to save DCs." Maybe I will just create a Stave.

Comment: @ruedi You're welcome. Metamagic except like Heighten Spell also usually doesn't increase a spell's saving throw DC (metamagic modifies the level of the slot the spell occupies yet don't change the spell's *actual* level--otherwise, nobody'd bother with Heighten Spell!). And, yes, a staff is a better deal if you can find a willing craftsman (Craft Staff has as a prerequisites caster level 11) and can afford it (spells in a staff have a minimum caster level 8, at least 1 higher than the typical minimum for a 4th-level spell in a wand).